# How can I avoid segmentation lines in gdspy?

Tags: python, mesh, autocad, quantum-computing, dxf

I am trying to draw and simulate a coplanar waveguide resonator. First I draw the design shown below in gdspy, then I perform an electromagnetic simulation using a finite element software. The horizontal lines make the simulation procedure cumbersome, since I have to add input and output ports for every segmented part. Moreover, meshing the design with these lines results in an unnecessary complex mesh grid.

Is there anyway to get rid of these lines using gdspy?

Thanks!
[Design in gdspy](https://ibb.co/B3YthJX)